# Thumbnail Image option is not showing in categories admin panel

Tags: category, ce-1.9.1.0

The "Thumbnail Image" option is not showing in the category admin panel.

see below image.

is this an issue with magento or issue with what?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento version 1.9.1.0 removes the feature of adding thumbnail image for category in Admin Panel. The Thumbnail attribute will normally be added when you install the sample data, but you can do it also manually with a few SQL queries or a custom setup script.

**eav_attribute table:**

```
INSERT INTO `eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`,
`attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`,
`frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`,
`is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`) VALUES(140, 3, 'thumbnail', NULL,
'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image', 'varchar', NULL, NULL, 'image', 'Thumbnail
Image', NULL, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

**catalog_eav_attribute table:**

```
INSERT INTO `catalog_eav_attribute` (`attribute_id`, `frontend_input_renderer`,
`is_global`, `is_visible`, `is_searchable`, `is_filterable`, `is_comparable`,
`is_visible_on_front`, `is_html_allowed_on_front`, `is_used_for_price_rules`,
`is_filterable_in_search`, `used_in_product_listing`, `used_for_sort_by`,
`is_configurable`, `apply_to`, `is_visible_in_advanced_search`, `position`,
`is_wysiwyg_enabled`, `is_used_for_promo_rules`) VALUES
(140, NULL, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

**eav_entity_attribute table:**

```
INSERT INTO `eav_entity_attribute` (`entity_attribute_id`, `entity_type_id`,  
`attribute_set_id`, `attribute_group_id`, `attribute_id`, `sort_order`) 
VALUES (337, 3, 3, 4, 140, 3);
```

**or use the custom setup script:**

```
<?php
$this->startSetup();

$attribute = array(
'thumbnail' => array(
'type'       => 'varchar',
'label'      => 'Thumbnail Image',
'input'      => 'image',
'backend'    => 'catalog/category_attribute_backend_image',
'required'   => false,
'sort_order' => 5,
'global'     => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'group'      => 'General Information',
),
);


$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::ENTITY, 'thumbnail', $attribute);
$this->endSetup();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i prefer using sql, but i'm getting ths error when try to run your sql: #1062 - Duplicate entry '140' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @AhmadDarwish the ID 140 was just from my example, for the queries 2 and 3 use the ID which was generated for the `thumbnail` attribute in the `eav_attribute` table.

Comment: It is working, only i've to change the the ID from 140 for my last free ID. thank you

Comment: This adds it to the database perfectly but is there something missing to actually call it in the frontend now since 1.9 because `$_category->getThumbnail()` doesn't work for me...

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 1.9.X version they disable module for category Thumbnail.

The thumbnail attribute is active by Mage_XmlConnect module.

So you just need to enable Mage_XmlConnect module to fix the issue.

You can find this module in app/etc/Mage_XmlConnect.xml

Now make it active:
replace false
with : true

Now clear your cache.

Comment: this worked like a charm for me, the other answer did not.